# Why there is the difference? np.inner vs inner

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def inner(x,y):
    result= 0
    t     = np.size(x)
    for i in range(1,t):
        result += x[i]*y[i]
    return result

j   = 1000
dif = [None]*j
for i in range(1,j):
    t = 1000
    x = np.random.rand(t)
    y = np.random.rand(t)
    dif[i] = np.inner(x,y)-inner(x,y)

plt.plot(dif)

dif[1:5]
[0.33178257274579437,
 0.07784229846930657,
 0.027789489089741437,
 0.23682733988198379]
```

I calculated the inner product of two n*1 array by both np.inner and a function written by myself.

I expected these two should be same. But, it turns out that there is actually some non-trivial difference.

Why is so? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `inner()`, you iterate from `1` to `t`. You should start from `0`.

Comment: Damn! I learned that array index in python starts from 0, just forgot this when I was actually doing it. Thanks.